# AlarmManager.setExact undefined

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm upgrading one of my apps to work properly on Kit Kat, and it depends on an exactly timed alarm. Now the [API changes page](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html) says that you must use a new call, setExact, to get this behavior back in 4.4. I'm attempting to use it but Eclipse is telling me that setExact is undefined, and indeed it doesn't appear in the auto-completion popup. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your build target (Project > Properties > Android) to API Level 19 (or higher, if you're reading this answer sometime in the future when we have higher than 19).

Comment: Ah, I changed the build target in my manifest but not in the project properties, thanks.